# sites/drupal folder not pushed to git repository

Tags: version-control

My .gitignore in the drupal root is as follows:

```
# Ignore configuration files that may contain sensitive information.
sites/*/*settings*.php

# Ignore paths that contain generated content.
files/
sites/*/files
sites/*/private
```

When I pushed it to a repository on github, the sites/default folder did not get pushed.

How to solve the issue?

Comment: Did you add any file under sites/default? If you ignore settings.php and files, what else was added under there? Empty folders for example won't be added. Try adding default.settings.php and then push.

Comment: I did a `git add -A` This should have added the default.settings.php by itself as it is not in .gitignore

Comment: try `git add sites/default/default.settings.php` then git will tell you if the file is excluded by your.gitignore file.

Comment: Output: The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
sites/default/default.settings.php
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added

Comment: oh! i think sites/*/*settings*.php is the issue. the * before settings

Comment: Oh, sorry forgot about your 'sites/*/*settings*.php' :) add a file under 'sites/default/files' called README and add it to git. This way git will create the files folder for you when you clone the site on a new location.

Comment: don't you think git will still ignore the files folder, as in my .gitignore there is sites/*/files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15204/discussion-between-pontus-nilsson-and-raj-praveen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a README file under `sites/default/files`
then force the file to be added to the repository by executing `git add -f sites/default/files/README` and push your files.

The `-f` flag will allow the file to be added by overriding your `.gitignore` file. 
The next time you clone the repository on a new location the folder `sites/default` and `sites/default/files` will be created by git.

When downloading Drupal the sites/default folder contains a file called default.settings.php. And one solution here would have been to add that file. But since your .gitignore excludes `sites/*/settings.php` `default.settings.php` file wont be added and Git will not add empty folders to the repository.

Comment: yes! removing the `*` before settings in  `sites/*/*settings*.php` in the .gitignore file will solve the issue.